# C# Wait for function to return yield break to continue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yield

I'm working in Unity, and I have a large script. At some point in the script, a coroutine, `foo` will be started. I want this coroutine to run another `IEnumerator` function, `bar`, but I don't want `bar` started as a coroutines. Rather, I need `foo` to start running, maybe yield a few times, call `bar`, wait until bar has finished running, and then continue running. At the moment I'm having to make `bar` `IEnumerable` to do:

```
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(foo());
}

IEnumerator foo () {
    //Do something up here
    foreach (int x in bar()) {
        yield return null; //Wait for bar to yield break
    }
    //Do more stuff down here
    yield break;
}


IEnumerable bar () {
    for (int x=0; x < 5; x++) {
        //Do Something 5 Times
        yield return x;
    }
    yield break;    
}
```

I've been searching, but I can't find the proper way to do this. There will of course be more than 10 such "bar" functions, so I don't want to have to make a for loop every time I want to call one. How can I call the other `IEnuerator` functions in this way?

Comment: What you're looking for is something frequently called a `yield foreach`.  It's a feature that doesn't exist (despite being rather frequently requested).  You're pretty much forced to do exactly what you're doing here.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for the quick response. What I forgot to ask up there is: Am I trying to force C# to do something it wasn't built to do? Is this not very C#-ish code? And if not, how should I be doing this same thing?

Comment: It is what I said; it's a commonly requested feature, but it doesn't exist.  That's simply it.  It may be added at some point in the future, or it may not be. Until it is, you'll need to settle for doing this.

Comment: Note that having a `yield break` at the end of the method isn't needed.  The end of the method is an implied `yield break`.  `yield break` exists, as a keyword, so that you can break at some place *other* than the end of the function.

Comment: @Servy What I'm trying to say is that it feels like I'm trying to force the language. I'm still relatively new to C#. How do other large programs handle calling other functions like this? They can't all use `foreach`'s every time. `IEnumerator`'s aside, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: When put in this particular situation you do indeed need to use a `foreach` each time.  Note that most people tend to write iterator blocks rather infrequently, and generally write code that relies on it's features through composing other functions that may use it (primarily LINQ methods) rather than using iterator blocks themselves.  In a non-iterator block there are simpler solutions (i.e. `Concat`).

Comment: @Servy Thank you for all your help. I was afraid that I was misusing the language this way. I'll attempt to reshape the code to better fit C#. Can you please post that last comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is something frequently called a `yield foreach`. It's a feature that doesn't exist (despite being rather frequently requested). You're pretty much forced to do exactly what you're doing here.

When you're writing an iterator block and you wish to yield each of the items of some other `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator` individually you have no choice but to explicitly enumerate the sequence and yield each item.  It would be nice if you could write something like `yield foreach Bar()` but you can't.  Your existing solution is as good as you can get using the current language features.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
class Program
{
    public class CoroutineThing
    {
        public IEnumerator foo()
        {
            //Do something up here
            var nTimesInvoked = 0;
            while (bar(nTimesInvoked++))
                yield return null; //Wait for bar to yield break
            //Do more stuff down here
            yield break;
        }
        bool bar(int nTimesInvoked)
        {
            if (nTimesInvoked < 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bar: {0}", nTimesInvoked);
                // Do something;
            }
            return nTimesInvoked < 4;
        }
    }
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var cor = new CoroutineThing();
        var nFoo = 0;
        var e = cor.foo();
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            nFoo++;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} times foo", nFoo);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```